# Google App Engine NDB post_create hook

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wanted to create a proper post_create (also post_get and post_put) hooks, similar to the ones I had on the DB version of my app.

Unfortunately I can't use has_complete_key.

The problem is quite known: lack of is_saved in a model.

Right now I have implemented it like this:

```
class NdbStuff(HooksInterface):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(NdbStuff, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self._is_saved = False

    def _put_async(self, post_hooks=True, **ctx_options):
        """ Implementation of pre/post create hooks. """

        if not self._is_saved:
            self._pre_create_hook()

        fut = super(NdbStuff, self)._put_async(**ctx_options)

        if not self._is_saved:
            fut._immediate_callbacks.insert(
                0,
                (
                    self._post_create_hook,
                    [fut],
                    {},
                )
            )
            self._is_saved = True

        if post_hooks is False:
            fut._immediate_callbacks = []

        return fut

    put_async = _put_async

    @classmethod
    def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
        obj = future.get_result()

        if obj is not None:
            obj._is_saved = True

        cls._post_get(key, future)

    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        if future.state == future.FINISHING:
            self._is_saved = True
        else:
            self._is_saved = False
        self._post_put(future)
```

Everything except the post_create hook seems to work.

The post_create is triggered every time the I use put_async without retrieving the object first.

I would really appreciate a clue on how to trigger the post_create_hook only once after the object was created.

Comment: Why don't use a factory to create the entities and set `_is_saved` explicitly to false on object creation.  Before you even start putting.  Then you don't have to try and play with __init__ methods.

Comment: @TimHoffman Can you be a little bit more specific?
I had _is_saved set both in init and right after class declaration and non of those solutions worked. is_saved just isn't updated to True when the put_async is being done

Comment: related discussion from 2011:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/qXfpCds051c

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are creating the NDBStuff class.

Any way if you creating an instance of a class, and you want to track `_is_saved` or something similar , use a factory to control creation and setting of the property, in this case it makes more sense to track _is_new for example.

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    some_prop = ndb.StringProperty()

    def _pre_put_hook(self):

        if getattr(self,'_is_new',None):
           self._pre_create_hook()
        # do something

    def _pre_create_hook(self):
        # do something on first save
        log.info("First put for this object")

    def _post_create_hook(self, future):
        # do something

    def _post_put_hook(self, future);
        if getattr(self,'_is_new', None):
           self._post_create_hook(future) 
           # Get rid of the flag on successful put, 
           # in case you make some changes and save again.
           delattr(self,'_is_new')

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        new_obj = cls(*args,**kwargs)
        settattr(new_obj,'_is_new',True)
        return new_obj
```

Then

```
    myobj = MyModel.factory(someargs)
    myobj.put()
    myobj.some_prop = 'test'
    myobj.put()
```

Will call the _pre_create_hook on the first put, and not on the second.

Always create the entities through the factory then you will always have the to call to _pre_create_hook executed.

Does that make sense ?

Comment: NDBStuff is just an example, it's supposed to be a base class for other NDB classes.

It was build, among others things, to make post_create possible while doing a put_async.

I thought about a solution similar to yours, but it would require a lot of changes in the flow and object creation. It's basically the same thing as adding a flag when initializing an object i.e. foo = MyModel(**args, is_new=True). Also I'm afraid that post_put may not clear the flag as it runs regardless of failure.


To sum things up: I'm just trying to add a nice and clean post_create in all my ndb classes.

Comment: Overriding init etc can be fraught with danger, unless you plan it carefully. I have just read through that thread and guido's suggestion is to override  `_from_pb` and setting the flag to indicate it hasn't been just created.  He also mentions using a factory.  You could also do the same using _post_get_hook, to set a flag - `not_new` and invert the check so that it's only set if the object has been retrieved.

Comment: overriding a private method like `_from_pb` seems to be a little risky. I was thinking about doing a similar thing with `Query` - what do you thing about this?
I think I may use the factory if the query option won't work.
About `_post_get_hook` - It looks like it's not triggered after a query, so I think it won't solve the problem.